# Alternative Button controls for winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Where can I find alternative button controls for vb.net Winform?

Comment: *Alternative* is not very precise description. What functionality is missing from the built-in buttons that prevents you from using them?

Comment: Looking for something that will allow for smaller size buttons but with readable text. I can't seem to get this with the button that comes with vs 2008.

Comment: Try a label - it has a click event. Or Segoe UI or Tahoma font and enter font size manually.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean since you can just choose the font so that it's any size you want and I've not seen anyone else mention this problem so I'm not sure if anyone will have written any specific controls for it. However, if you want to customize the look other options would be to override the `OnPaint` and draw it yourself or create an image that contains the text and show that image instead of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Vendors that offer button controls with more options than standard WinForms:

infragistics.com

telerik.com

devexpress.com

I'd recommend downloading trial versions and see if you can make their controls do what you are failing to accomplish with the built in button control

Or,  you could create an image that shows the text you want and attach it to the button instead of text. This is not as ideal as if you can find a small readable font though!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but it could be useful for other:
http://namtuk.com/mycommandbutton_DOTNET.aspx

It supports a lot of button style like Office 2010, Windows 8 Metro, ...